# Live Video Chat Streaming In Android?

Tags: java, android, video-streaming

Will you please help me  for shareing how can I create a sample video chating (Like Video Calling in 3G) uisng Internet in Android and Desktop. It's like I may be on the desktop, and my friends will be in the different Android phone, we all can come online and have video chat.
How it is possible?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550847/streaming-video-from-android-camera-to-server) previous SO post will put you in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

I think that it would be good to use ffmpeg. Bambuser - a live streaming service has an open source [ffmpeg for android](http://bambuser.com/opensource) project.

Comment: How to use thi API ? can you pls say