# Android liveStream video

Tags: android, video, video-streaming, android-camera, live-streaming

I'm trying to do an Android app that can stream video (live) from the device camera to another device. How can I do this? Anyone can give me tips or some kind of tutorial / code ? I really need some help because I don't know how can I solve this. I read a lot about this, i've tried some examples but until now without success. 
thanks

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/sipdroid/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Live-stream video from one android phone to another over WiFi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14401340/live-stream-video-from-one-android-phone-to-another-over-wifi)

Answer (score 1):

There has already been talk done about this over here. Hope it helps:

[Streaming video from Android camera to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550847/streaming-video-from-android-camera-to-server)

Edit: http://code.google.com/p/ipcamera-for-android/ <= here is a project that does what you want to do, you just need to adapt it to your needs :)