# media recorder start failed: MEDIA_ERROR_UNSUPPORTED (start failed: -1010) while trying to record video to socket

Tags: android, sockets, video-streaming, mediarecorder

I'm trying to implement the solution from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14432887/1665247) to record video to socket (and then read it from the socket in the player side, When the ultimate goal is to broadcast video in real time)

but when trying to call the start() of the madiarecorder there is exception: start failed:-1010

the API says about this constant:

> public static final int MEDIA_ERROR_UNSUPPORTED
>
> Added in API level 17 Bitstream is conforming to the related coding
>   standard or file spec, but the media framework does not support the
>   feature.

but I'm guessing that if people check this answer to be effective it is supported in some way- so please

point at me, what's my mistake??

here is the code i'm using:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Camera mCamera;
    private MediaRecorder mMediaRecorder;
    private Socket socket;
    private Preview mPreView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        try {

            socket = new Socket("10.0.0.4",8080);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // this is your network socket
        ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = ParcelFileDescriptor.fromSocket(socket);
        mPreView=new Preview(this);
        mCamera = getCameraInstance();
        mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mCamera.lock();
        mCamera.unlock();
        mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
        // this is the unofficially supported MPEG2TS format, suitable for
        // streaming (Android 3.0+)
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(8);
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.DEFAULT);
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(pfd.getFileDescriptor());
    //  mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(null);
        try {
            mMediaRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mMediaRecorder.start();
    }

    /** A safe way to get an instance of the Camera object. */
    public static Camera getCameraInstance() {
        Camera c = null;
        try {
            c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
        }
        return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    class Preview extends ViewGroup implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
    {
SurfaceView mSurface;
SurfaceHolder mHolder;
        public Preview(Context context) {
            super(context);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            mSurface=new SurfaceView(context);
            addView(mSurface);
            mHolder=mSurface.getHolder();
        }
        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
        @Override
        protected void onLayout(boolean arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3,
                int arg4) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    }

}
```

**why media recorder doesn't support it? and how can I solve it?**

thank you for giving your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

I replaced this line:

```
mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(8);
```

with this:

```
mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
```

Comment: Btw. your code will fail on devices (mostly tablets) that have only a front facing camera as Camera.open() will return a null pointer in this case. You have to use Camera.open(id) in this case.

Answer (score 0):

With a MediaRecorder start failed it is important to check your settings for the media recorder and make sure they are all possible for your hardware so I would check things like:

```
mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource();
mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat();
mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder();
```

etc.

If any of these are incorrect or unavailable for the hardware then this is how MediaRecorder will let you know

Comment: how do i check if hardware supports these settings?