# how to implement live video streaming from phone to server in android?

Tags: android

I want to implement live video streaming from my phone to server in android.Till now what i have done so far , I have captured video and save it to sdcard and then uploaded it to server,it is doing well, but i want to record and send my video to server instantly.Is there any sample code for this or can anyone help me in this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14401340/live-stream-video-from-one-android-phone-to-another-over-wifi

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550847/streaming-video-from-android-camera-to-server

Comment: Dear Qadir Hussain I have checked both these solutions but couldn't find any perfect solution for my question.If you any sample code please let me know