# Android wireless remote camera

Tags: java, android, camera, remote-access

Given a Android tablet and a camera ([Samsung Android](http://www.samsung.com/uk/consumer/mobile-devices/galaxy-camera/galaxy-camera/EK-GC110ZWABTU)).

Is it possible to use remote camera like a build in camera? A local camera I could open using the [camera API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html) but how to make the camera from another device locally available?

Do I need to have a second app on the other device and make some video streaming for live preview or is it possible to create a link with drivers in Linux?

Another solution could be this [open source video streaming lib](https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming) I found. Combined with [VLC as client app](https://wiki.videolan.org/AndroidCompile/) that could work. But I would also need a back channel to control the camera. This look very complicated to me.

Samsung Camera also supposed to support DLNA but I think this is only useful after a picture war taken not for live preview. Right?

Comment: "Is it possible to use remote camera like a build in camera? A local camera I could open using the camera API but how to make the camera from another device locally available?" -- only with some sort of a ROM mod that exports an IP-based camera as part of the `Camera` API.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14401340/live-stream-video-from-one-android-phone-to-another-over-wifi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played around with [IP Webcam](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pas.webcam&hl=de). It creates a live view of the camera as I needed.