# video streaming from an android phone to another android phone over a WiFi connection

Tags: android, sockets, streaming

for video streaming from an android phone to another android phone over a WiFi connection, i am using the code that was cited in

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14401340/live-stream-video-from-one-android-phone-to-another-over-wifi
```

this is the server code:

```
    // this is your network socket
    ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = ParcelFileDescriptor.fromSocket(socket);
    mCamera = getCameraInstance();
    mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mCamera.unlock();
    mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);
    mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
    // this is the unofficially supported MPEG2TS format, suitable for streaming (Android 3.0+)
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(8);
    mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.DEFAULT);
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(pfd.getFileDescriptor());
    //mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mPreview.getHolder().getSurface());
    mMediaRecorder.prepare();
    mMediaRecorder.start();
```

and this is the client code:

```
    // this is your network socket, connected to the server
    ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = ParcelFileDescriptor.fromSocket(socket);
    mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(pfd.getFileDescriptor());
    mMediaPlayer.prepare();
    mMediaPlayer.start();
```

But was is the code for creating the socket for both sides, if i am using udp protocol?

(I dint ask it in a comment there, because i dont hava enough reputation)