# Is it possible to broadcast from Android phone camera to web

Tags: java, android, web-applications, live-streaming, broadcasting

So, I'm doing a project in the university and thinking about broadcasting from an Android phone camera.

It's a bit like Hangout in G+, but it will be a one-way connection.

For example, I broadcast my self through my phone and people who want to watch this broadcast can watch it with their phone or from the website.

So, I just wonder if this idea is possible( let say that I'm not concerned about internet connectivity speed or any limitation about internet) and if it possible, how should I begin?

Comment: Does this answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550847/streaming-video-from-android-camera-to-server