# android - how to stream video from phone to server?

Tags: android, streaming, video-streaming, audio-streaming, live-streaming

I'm currently working on an app that has the ability to stream video from phone to server. is there any example online that I can take a look at? I've tried [spydroid](https://github.com/fyhertz/spydroid-ipcamera) and [sipdroid](https://code.google.com/p/sipdroid/), but none of them seem to work for me. can someone please give me a hint? All I want to do is being able to send the video that I'm capturing from my phone to server, and people will be able to view the video online.

many thanks

Comment: This question may be a duplicate, or at least is closely related to, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18588086/android-how-to-stream-video-from-phone-to-server and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550847/streaming-video-from-android-camera-to-server