# receiving video stream from pc while using ip camera on Android

Tags: android, camera, video-streaming, ip-camera

I am new to android and I am wondering is it possible to use ip camera in the background service while receiving video stream from a pc?

If yes, is there a good reference to start?

I have can build a ip camera but I don't know how to combine the two functionality together. Will VLC be a good solution for this?

I have also been searching for similar applications but couldn't find one. And it seems that the camera service has to be fetched in active mode ( not sure if I am right)

Could anyone give me some advices?

Comment: What do you mean by "using ip camera"?

Comment: I want to fetch the video from camera and send it to the server for processing. After this, send it back to my android device and display on the device screen

Comment: Should it be in real-time or do you want to send the entire video, process it and then send it back?

Comment: It should be in real time, is it possible to use asynchronous class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general it is possible.
Streaming video to a server is feasible, I did it myself several times.
Streaming video to the device is also possible, you have built in APIs for that.

The only problem that you'll need to figure out yourself how to accomplish is that for both sending the video and displaying the video you must have a video that displays the video (yes, for the device to server also).

For device to server take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550847/streaming-video-from-android-camera-to-server)
For server to device take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html)

Please note, the MediaPlayer network infrastructure is somewhat limited, it is possible that you'll need to build the network layer yourself, depending on your server capabilities.

Good luck

Comment: Hi sorry for getting back to you so late.  If I understand what you are saying, we cannot generate a streamed video feed back to the app.  Is this true? We are using OpenCV for realtime processing that we want to display back out on the tablet.  We would use it in an Android app alone but the idea is that someone can choose how to process it remotely if that makes sense.

Comment: No, I didn't say that :-) Ofcourse you can, you already see tons of apps such as Skype, Google Talk, etc' where you have two way video.
I said you can use the MediaRecorder and MediaPlayer to achieve that. You will only need to figure out what to do with the fact that you must allocate a preview view for the recorded video.