# Capture and stream video in Android

Tags: android, video-streaming, video-capture

I want to capture both front and back camera of an android device and stream it to a server over internet. Server must support multiple connected devices. I know how to capture video but I have no clue how to: 
1- stream video and
2- how to play streamed video in browser

I will be great thankful If you know open source app/lib or any documentation about this subject.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check this wonderful project ?

https://code.google.com/p/ipcamera-for-android/

[Streaming video from Android camera to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550847/streaming-video-from-android-camera-to-server)