# android streaming camera over 3g

Tags: android, udp, video-streaming, android-camera, android-mediarecorder

My application must stream device camera over 3g connection to server .

I follow this question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550847/streaming-video-from-android-camera-to-server) and use with success [libstreaming](https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming) ([spydroid streaming lib](https://code.google.com/p/spydroid-ipcamera/)) on wifi.

If device and server aren't on same lan, I need a 3g connection to do same thing, but I think there are problems caused by NAT .

Packets of libstreaming are sent by UDP , and over 3g they are blocked.

There are other solutions? Maybe using streaming over TCP I can reach my purpose.

Comment: bear in mind: Use UDP for speed-sensitive cases, and TCP for Reliability.

Answer (score 0):

When you are outside of the [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) you can't send data inside.

**Unless:**

1. Someone asks for that data.

   - In case 1 you need to make a UDP server with the fix IP and request
     its data by IP:PORT
2. Using [port forwarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding).

   - In case 2 you need to set a port forwarding at the router level.