# streaming video from android camera to pc?

Tags: android, video, streaming, video-streaming, android-camera

What is the best (performance wise) way to get and stream a video from an android device's camera to a PC?

I have seen this question asked here before and there exist a few open source programs that do just that, but there exist multiple ways from which I don't know which one is the best!
for example:

1. Should the android part be written in c++ or java (performance/api wise)?
2. Which api should I use to get the video from camera?
3. What is the best way to stream the video?

I don't intend to support old android versions (<4.x), so if the best way/api is relatively new it's fine by me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Streaming video from Android camera to server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550847/streaming-video-from-android-camera-to-server)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Android development but I'll try to answer.

I suppose that the actual encoding of the raw image data is probably done on hardware chip (otherwise software encoding would probably kill your battery) and it looks like [MediaCodec class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html) is exactly what you need. I suppose you want to implement some kind of live streaming service and the latency is important. If so, then you should stick to UDP based transmission methods. Using [RTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_Transport_Protocol) protocol or [MPEG-TS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_Transport_Protocol) container format would be the best choice for this purpose. Of course you can also use TCP based methods for streaming like [HLS](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-18) or [DASH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Adaptive_Streaming_over_HTTP) (both of them use HTTP).

You should also take a look at **Table 1** [Core media format and codec support](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html):

It tells us for example that using H.264 AVC Encoder supports MPEG-TS container and that HLS version 3 is also supported for Android 4.0 and above.