# In Android, possible to save video directly in Amazon server while recording

Tags: android, video, amazon-s3

While uploading the videos/audio files from my application,mostly i followed the following ways,

1. Record the file (video/audio)
2. Save into Internal/External Storage (inside application folder)
3. Then upload in server.

here my question is, whether its possible to save directly in the server (Amazon s3 or others). Why i'm asking this, while i using [Periscope](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tv.periscope.android&hl=en)  application they streaming the video as well as stored the video in their server.

Comment: Check out this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550847/streaming-video-from-android-camera-to-server

Answer (score 2):

Checkout LibStreaming : https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming or some of the suggestion in : [Streaming video from Android camera to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550847/streaming-video-from-android-camera-to-server)

Answer (score 0):

You can see this [github](https://github.com/Kickflip/kickflip-android-sdk) or use ffmpeg

Answer (score 0):

I think that it all depends on the importance of your video. When you use your original approach you guarantee that you have the full video in hand (device) and you can make sure it will be fully uploaded to your server. On the other hand, streaming it directly to the server can make you lose frames (connectivity hiccups and such) and hurt the video. I'm sure that streaming is done using UDP which makes loosing packages a really good option.