# How do I stream live video from my android phone to my pc using the phone camera?

Tags: android, video, mobile, live, live-streaming

I want to stream live video from the camera app to my computer, how would I do that? Would I use the camera API? I don't want to run a server or anything like in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550847/streaming-video-from-android-camera-to-server), I want the connection to be completely wired.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a WebRTC solution. I'm sure there are many implementations but [Kurento](https://www.kurento.org/) would be one example.